# How to solve for variable x

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm not sure how to find the variable x since it can obtain complex values. Can anyone help me find a real value?

$$-2.9623 = \frac{6x}{x^3 + x + 2}$$

Comment: Do you know how to solve cubic equations? You can look it up

Comment: Rewrite it as $x^3 + (1 + \frac{6}{2.9623}) x + 2 = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We write the equation as:
$$
 -2.9623  (x^3 + x + 2)- 6x =0
$$
We write the left hand side as $f(x)$
Investigating by standard method of calculus we find that there is only one real root.
To solve - implement very simple Newton Raphson method:
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n-f(x_n)/f'(x_n)
$$
here $f'(x)=-8.9623 - 8.8869 x^2$.

Starting from $x=1$, we get convergence after 4 steps (I implemented in Excel, the left column is $x_n$ and the right is $x_{n+1}$):

[image]

The  approximation for the real solution is thus  $x\approx-0.59236$.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend isolating $x$ differently. Set the whole equation so that $0=f(x)$, where $f(x) = \frac{6x}{x^3+x+2}+2.9623$. From this setup alone, we know that we're looking for a negative value because the only way to add $a$ to $b$ and get $0$ is if $a=-b$.

We have the problem, too, that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = 2.9623$. So, let's try $-1$ first:

$$\frac{6(-1)}{(-1)^3-1+2}=\frac{-6}{-1-1+2},$$

which is undefined. So, because we know that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x) = 2.9623$ and $x<0$ and that $f(-1)$ is undefined, we must have $-1<x<0$.

At this, point, I would do guess and check. If you have a calculator, plug in $-0.5, -0.25$, and $-0.75$ to see in which range it is. Then just keep cutting it in half until you get your answer.

(HINT: Because this is a cubic function and you're up to 4 decimal places in your constant, the answer will probably not be pretty. Just be happy once you get to your 4th or 5th sig-fig and that'll be good enough.)

Comment: This is a nice answer, although it should be noted that an undefined value is not the same as the empty set! It would be best to just use words: "$\cdots = \frac{-6}{-1-1+2}$, which is undefined." Also, what do you mean by $x=-\infty \to 2.9623$? How can $x$ equal $-\infty$, and how can $-\infty$ tend to any fixed value?

Comment: That's my fault. I meant to say that $x\to-\infty$ then the function's value tends to 2.9623. I'm not very knowledgeable about formating in maths; I'm somewhat self-taught and use this site as a new hobby.

Comment: No problem. This is otherwise a good explanation. I named your function $f$ to make it easier to refer to; I think that solves the problem.